# jQuery Cycle Plugin Help

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am trying to build a sliding rotator with jQuery Cycle plugin but am having some trouble with a custom display that I need...Basically I have the slides and on top of each slide there is a textbox with text.  I just want the slides to slide but I want the text to fadeout and then in when the new slide comes in.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="home-slider">
     <div class="slide">
          <img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
          <div class="text-box">
               <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="slide">
          <img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
          <div class="textblock">
               <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function onBefore() {
    jQuery("#home-slider .slide .textblock").hide();    
}
function onAfter() { 
    jQuery("#home-slider .slide .textblock").fadeIn('fast');
}
jQuery("#home-slider").cycle({
        speed:  500, 
        timeout: 3000,
    after:   onAfter,
    before: onBefore

});
```

So the slides are working fine but the text are sliding with it when I want them to just fade in/out instead.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sliding you have to set the `fx` property either to '`scrollHorz` or `scorllVert`. Take a look at this working demo. Aslo you have some typo's in your class names.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CEyf3/2/)**

Comment: no, everything slides fine as I stated...I just need the text not to slide but fade in/ out

Comment: It is working as you need, take a look at the demo. The text just fades and not slides.

Comment: Not quite if you see the text isn't being faded out...it only fades in..I need it to fade out...

Comment: @Rick - Since the textblock is a part of the sliding div so it is technically not possible unless you animate it explicitly. I have found another solution which is exactly what you are looking for. Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CEyf3/2/.

Comment: I just can't see why it can't be done if there are the two functions onBefore and onAfter provided...I tried putting the fadeout on onBefore and of course that didn't work as you probably tried as well. I believe there is a way to target the current slide and if so, we should be able to say current slide fadeout onBefore...strange...thanks for all your inputs so far though...

Comment: You want to `fadeOut` only the `textblock` in the slide which has image also. When we call `fadeOut` in `onBefore` it starts fading but at the same time cycle plugin start sliding also so you will see the textblock moving along with the slide. You cannot make cycle plugin wait untill fadeOut completes its animation. I hope you understand this.

Comment: Why can't we make the cycler wait until it fades out?  I was able to do this when I created this slide from scratch...but just can't reproduce this with this plugin...I think the plugin should have a callback that waits for complete prior to continuing the next slide...

Comment: Here we want to wait in the onBefore callback and not wait for next slide to start.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "#" in your jquery calls and its called text-box in one section of your html:

```
function onBefore() {    
  jQuery("#home-slider .slide .text-box","#home-slider .slide .textblock").hide(); 
}
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {     
  jQuery("#home-slider .slide .text-box","#home-slider .slide .textblock").fadeIn('fast');    
  jQuery("#home-slider .slide").css("zIndex","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that the slide div is already hidden, so onbefore doesn't have any effect as it is shown afterwards.

One way around this could be to use text-indent to have it off the screen and then hide it onafter, reposition the text correctly and then fade in.

Another option is to have a div overtop the text to hide it and then hide the below text onafter and remove the div and fade in.

A third option is to choose only the images in the cycle function.  jQuery("#home-slider img").cycle or if that doesn't work, then have them in a separate div to cycle through.